# Set a tikz node's contents from a style

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-styles

In tikz, how can I set a node's contents from a style ?

For example, instead of writing this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix[matrix of nodes] {
    |[name=A-Foo]|A.Foo & |[name=B-Foo]|B.Foo & \dots \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would like to write this, but the option `contents` doesn't exist:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  nc/.style 2 args={name={#1-#2}, content={#1.#2}}
  ]
  \matrix[matrix of nodes] {
    |[nc={A}{Foo}]| & |[nc={B}{Foo}]| & \dots \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can’t really/officially. You can misuse the `font` key or even better `execute at begin cell` which may not always work or have downsides as it is executed rather early. Though, in a matrix you can setup the `execute at begin cell` and `execute at end cell` in a way which would make this possible. What you also can do is use `label=center:{#1.#2}` (in fact, this adds another node with that content) but then the actual node doesn’t get re-sized and such things.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks, `execute at end cell={\node{#1.#2};}` seems to do the trick. If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: That should read “or even better `execute at begin node`” in my previous comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Within a `matrix`, this can be done with a small fix to the `\tikz@lib@matrix@end@cell` macro.

The following solution adds the contents of the `content` key add the *end* of the node (but not an “empty” node.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\makeatletter
\def\tikz@lib@matrix@end@cell@{%
  \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/content}%
  \iftikz@lib@matrix@plain\else%
    \expandafter\egroup\expandafter;\fi}
\tikzset{
  content/.initial=,
  matrix of nodes with the possibility to set the content/.style={
    matrix of nodes,
    /utils/exec=\let\tikz@lib@matrix@end@cell\tikz@lib@matrix@end@cell@}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[nc/.style 2 args={name={#1-#2}, content={#1.#2}}]
  \matrix[matrix of nodes with the possibility to set the content] {
    |[nc={A}{Foo}]| & |[nc={B}{Foo}]| & \dots \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[
   matrix of nodes with the possibility to set the content,
   nodes in empty cells, content={\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn}] {
    & {} & {} & {} & {} \\
 {} &    & {} & {} & {} \\
 {} & {} &    & {} & {} \\
 {} & {} & {} &    & {} \\
 {} & {} & {} & {} &    \\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]
[image]