# Problem with a parametric "node contents" style for matrix of nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

This is related with [Set a tikz node's contents from a style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/133222/1952), but this question and corresponding answer are eight years old and `node contents` option was not available at that time.

My intention was to answer [Access tikz matrix cell content to programmatically set cell style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/621883/1952) with a node's style where `fill` and `node contents` were defined from a parameter which could be fixed into every matrix cell. Something like:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[mystyle/.style={draw, node contents={#1}}, 
                    mystyle/.default={A}]
\matrix[matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells, nodes={mystyle}]{
    |[mystyle={B}]|&&\\
     &&\\};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

As this doesn't work, I finally replaced `node contents` by `label=center:#1` which works when a certain size is fixed for the main node.

So the question is why previous code doesn't work?

This is the code with previous test and the desired but not working solution.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells, nodes={draw, node contents={A}}]{
&&\\&&\\};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[mystyle/.style={draw, node contents={A}}]
\matrix[matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells, nodes={mystyle}]{
&&\\&&\\};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[mystyle/.style={draw, node contents={#1}}]
\matrix[matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells, nodes={mystyle={A}}]{
&&\\&&\\};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[mystyle/.style={draw, node contents={#1}}, mystyle/.default={A}]
\matrix[matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells, nodes={mystyle}]{
&&\\&&\\};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[mystyle/.style={draw, node contents={#1}}, mystyle/.default={A}]
\matrix[matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells, nodes={mystyle}]{
|[mystyle={B}]|&&\\&&\\};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`node contents` 1) can only be used as a last key in node options and 2) it changes the node syntax.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes=draw]
  % without `node contents`, node parser keeps working until a pair of braces
  \node {text};
  % with `node contents`, node parser stops immediately
  \node at (1,0) [node contents=text];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But with `matrix of nodes`, neither of the two conditions hold.

1. Any style passed to option `nodes={...}`, actually `every node/.append style={...}`, is executed before a node parser begins (and when the parser begins it initializes with `node contents={}`), hence `nodes={node contents={...}}` will have no effect.
2. With `matrix of nodes`, a matrix cell will always has the form of

   ```tex
   execute at begin cell={\node[...] \bgroup}
   execute at end cell  ={\egroup;}
   ```

   Noticed the `\bgroup <cell content> \egroup` forming a normal syntax of node content.

You may be interested in how `matrix of nodes` is defined on top of `execute at (begin|end) cell` and more matrix styles, in [`tikzlibrarymatrix.code.tex`](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/master/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarymatrix.code.tex).

Alternatively, I think your original task can be solved with option `execute at begin node`, plus a little bit trick:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[execute at begin node={\mytext},
                    execute at begin node once/.store in=\mytext,
                    mystyle/.style={draw, execute at begin node once={#1}}, 
                    mystyle/.default={A}]
\matrix[matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells, nodes={mystyle}]{
    |[mystyle={B}]|&&\\
     &&\\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]